# How can i create a white box like the example in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I was trying to create a white box like the example, that shows information when i click on a button (Web Development, Software engineering, System Administration).
I would like to have a tip for this with CSS, also, do i need a JavaScript for that?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR9s6.png)

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```css
.box{
margin:40px;
position: relative;
box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
padding: 30px;
}
.box:before{
content: "";
position:absolute;
top: -30px;
left: 50px;
border: 15px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some content about development
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but i need a way to link it with the orange box

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helpful. Details can be edited on .css.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>W3.CSS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <body>
    
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h2>W3.CSS Modal</h2>
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Open Modal</button>
    
      <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
        <div class="w3-modal-content">
          <div class="w3-container">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
            <p>Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
            <p>Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
                
    </body>
    </html>
```

Link to test [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_modal)

Comment: I don't need a modal in this case, i just need a way to link the orange box with the white box

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```css
.container p {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #FF2000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 110px;
    padding-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <p>Your Text</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but it was more about how to link the orange box with the white box

Comment: Sorry I'm stupid ahahaha, I'll see what I can do, I think you should use use the display:absolute propriety